# Plotting 3D ploint cloud

Tags: matlab

May I know what is error shown below?

Error using scatter3 (line 77)
C must be a single color, a vector the same length as X, or an M-by-3 matrix.

It appear when I write a code:

```
scatter3(points(:,1),points(:,2),points(:,3),50,color,'fill');
```

The color value mentioned is display as below:

color =

```
0.6118    0.6118    0.6118
0.9216    0.7490    0.5216
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.5922    0.5216    0.4118
0.9176    0.7020    0.4392
0.1412    0.1882    0.1569
0.7137    0.5176    0.3451
0.5765    0.3294    0.1176
0.6902    0.4471    0.2275
0.6039    0.5490    0.4078
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.1529    0.2471    0.2314
     0         0         0
0.4784    0.4902    0.3961
     0         0         0
0.2039    0.1765    0.0745
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.1725    0.2314    0.2000
0.8118    0.5569    0.2980
     0         0         0
0.9098    0.6902    0.4745
0.2588    0.2314    0.1176
0.0902    0.1490    0.1137
0.1725    0.1333    0.0784
0.5725    0.5843    0.5020
     0         0         0
0.8510    0.6196    0.3843
0.3961    0.3608    0.2314
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.4235    0.3843    0.2471
0.2824    0.2824    0.1294
0.6667    0.6745    0.6157
0.3020    0.2588    0.1451
0.0863    0.0627    0.0314
0.6039    0.5216    0.3843
0.7686    0.5804    0.3569
0.7608    0.5804    0.3569
0.2824    0.2000    0.0784
0.5255    0.4392    0.3490
     0         0         0
     0         0         0
0.2353    0.2275    0.1333
     0         0         0
0.6118    0.5255    0.4275
     0         0         0
0.6118    0.6118    0.6118
0.9216    0.7490    0.5216
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.5922    0.5216    0.4118
0.9176    0.7020    0.4392
0.1412    0.1882    0.1569
0.7137    0.5176    0.3451
0.5765    0.3294    0.1176
0.6902    0.4471    0.2275
0.6039    0.5490    0.4078
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.1529    0.2471    0.2314
     0         0         0
0.4784    0.4902    0.3961
     0         0         0
0.2039    0.1765    0.0745
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.1725    0.2314    0.2000
0.8118    0.5569    0.2980
     0         0         0
0.9098    0.6902    0.4745
0.2588    0.2314    0.1176
0.0902    0.1490    0.1137
0.1725    0.1333    0.0784
0.5725    0.5843    0.5020
     0         0         0
0.8510    0.6196    0.3843
0.3961    0.3608    0.2314
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.4235    0.3843    0.2471
0.2824    0.2824    0.1294
0.6667    0.6745    0.6157
0.3020    0.2588    0.1451
0.0863    0.0627    0.0314
0.6039    0.5216    0.3843
0.7686    0.5804    0.3569
0.7608    0.5804    0.3569
0.2824    0.2000    0.0784
0.5255    0.4392    0.3490
     0         0         0
     0         0         0
0.2353    0.2275    0.1333
     0         0         0
0.6118    0.5255    0.4275
     0         0         0
0.6314    0.6431    0.6392
0.9059    0.7098    0.4941
0.7804    0.7804    0.7804
0.9333    0.7137    0.4784
0.7765    0.5294    0.2784
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.6078    0.5176    0.3922
0.7373    0.5608    0.3333
0.7216    0.5176    0.3020
0.4353    0.4000    0.3608
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.0627    0.1882    0.1412
0.2157    0.2118    0.2392
0.6392    0.4000    0.1922
0.1098    0.1647    0.1569
0.5765    0.5843    0.5373
0.6706    0.4235    0.2510
0.1412    0.1176    0.0471
0.5529    0.5569    0.5216
     0         0         0
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.8667    0.6588    0.4392
0.7804    0.5137    0.2941
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.1686    0.1333    0.0588
0.8196    0.6000    0.3725
0.1961    0.1922    0.0902
0.5765    0.4980    0.3804
0.2039    0.2902    0.2667
0.4627    0.4039    0.2588
0.2706    0.2431    0.1216
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
0.7686    0.5647    0.3451
     0         0         0
0.5843    0.5137    0.4118
0.1569    0.1686    0.0941
0.2627    0.1451    0.0784
0.6627    0.4510    0.2706
0.2588    0.1961    0.1216
0.1686    0.1176    0.0510
0.5647    0.5686    0.5451
0.5608    0.5686    0.5255
0.5176    0.5373    0.4784
0.6549    0.4784    0.2784
0.5843    0.5922    0.5686
0.7490    0.7647    0.7333
0.1569    0.1255    0.0431
0.2471    0.2039    0.1451
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason already. This is just because the number of color recoreded is not same with number of coordinates of color.